# How to specify a starting city using the TSP package in R

Tags: r, dataset

I have been trying to solve a TSP problem using the TSP package in R. I have created a large symmetric distance matrix with 0 entries along the leading diagonal. I want to be able to specify the first city as the starting city for methods such as `nearest_insertion`. I have successfully used the `"nn"` method and specified the starting city using the code below:

`tsp1=TSP(distance_matrix)`
`solve_TSP(tsp1,method="nn",control=list(start=1))`

However the argument `control=list(start=1))` doesn't work for the `"nearest_insertion"` method. Instead I get the error message:

> Error in x[is.na(x)] <- Inf : 
>     INTEGER() can only be applied to a 'integer', not a 'double`

For sample data I have been using the following distance matrix:

`distance_matrix=matrix(c(0,1,2,1,0,5,2,5,0),3,3)`

How can I specify the first city as the starting city for the `"nearest_insertion"` method?

Answer (score 6):

I know it's a bit late but I had the same problem, and that's how you need to do:

```
solve_TSP(prova, method = "nearest_insertion", start=3L)
```

This declares 3 as an integer, same as `as.integer(3)`, yet avoiding the function call.

This also works for other methods.